# bash: ./prob: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: execute-command

I tried to run the binary given below but found the following error. May you kindly shed light on it?

```
ankur@ankur-G3-3500:~/Desktop/JUNO_Analytical_for_CC$ ./prob
bash: ./prob: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
ankur@ankur-G3-3500:~/Desktop/JUNO_Analytical_for_CC$ file prob
prob: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), with debug_info, not stripped
ankur@ankur-G3-3500:~/Desktop/JUNO_Analytical_for_CC$ uname -a
Linux ankur-G3-3500 5.11.0-43-generic #47~20.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 13 11:06:56 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: `prob` is perhaps a shared object file, rather than an executable program? Did you compile it yourself? if so, please [edit] your question to indicate the steps.

Comment: What does `file prob;ldd prob` tell you? Please [edit] your Question, don't use Add comment. Read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting